# Angular watch for object reference and value change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is there a way in Angular to watch both object reference change and value change?

I use `$scope.$watch(..., ..., true)` to check for changing values and `$scope.$watch(..., ...)` for a change of the reference of the object, but what happens if the reference is changed, but with a copy of the previous object (different reference, same values). What's the best way of watching both?

Comment: Let's assume it is - what are my options?

Comment: Thanks for not answering the question Chandermani!